# PHP And JavaScript onClick?

Tags: php, javascript

I have the following:

`onClick='<?php $message = $_row['message']; $poster = $_row['poster'];?> deletePost();'"`

I have a `while()` statement before the `onClick` (applied to a delete button) but need to set the values of the `$poster` and `$message` variables so the PHP script deletes the right record. Any better way to do this?

I am getting the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

Comment: Is that code being executed on the server, or in a browser? Or you want to write an universal one?

Comment: It's executed in the browser. It runs with JavaScript, hence calling the `deletePost();` function after it

Comment: 1. Can you post a bigger chunk of the code, please?

2. Why are you setting PHP values in the onClick in the first place? Neither one of those variables seem to have anything to do with it.

3. Try screwing around with the white-space to get rid of the error. Maybe the "?&gt;" needs a space before it. Does the error indicate that this is the correct line?
3.

Comment: The function that gets called:

http://pastebin.com/vKpTvbhV

The way it is called:

`onClick='return deletePost($_row['message'],$_row['poster']);'`

I pass them through the javascript function, which then deletes the correct row from a mySQL database, since the delete button is inside of a `while()` loop.

Comment: I can help in it but for this i have to see the complete sentence of your code which you are using right now..

Comment: PHP does not fit with javascript this way. The PHP code you entered will be executed regardless of the click in question. Instead, you should set your variables higher (at the top of the relevant control structure), and then add your function etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting the PHP code to run when the button is clicked? If so then you are wrong - this is not how PHP works - PHP generates HTML which is then rendered on the browser. This snippet of PHP will run every tme you generate the page - not when the button is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is good idea to implement.. rather than this you can pass those variable in deletePost() function like this

```
onClick= return deletePost($_row['message'],$_row['poster']);
```

adjust single/double quotes according to your need

Comment: I think you are confusing where the different languages are used. You cannot connect to your database from Javascript, since its running on your user's browser. 

To do what you are trying to achieve you need to make an AJAX request to a PHP script on the server with the required arguments to delete the post from the database. If this is what you need to do I suggest searching for existing answers on AJAX implementations.

Comment: deletePost is Javascript where you have used it as PHP, while not declaring anything related to PHP as onClick should be used in javascript.